# R accumulating memory in each iteration with large input files

Tags: r, loops, memory

I am reading around 20,000 text files in a for loop for sentiment analysis. Each file is of around 20-40 MB size. In each loop, I am taking out some sentiment counts (just a 2 numbers) out of my input text and storing it in a dataframe. The issue is, in each iteration, I can see R is cumulatively accumulating memory. After 10,000 files I see around 13GB memory allocation for R in my task manager. I tried gc() and rm() to delete objects after each iteration, but still it does not work. The logic is as I am using the same objects iteratively R is not releasing memory used in the previous iterations.

```
for(i in 1:20,000){
 filename <- paste0("file_", i, ".txt")
 text <- readLines(filename)

 # Doing sentiment analysis based on dictionary based approach

 # Storing sentiment counts in dataframe

 # Removing used objects
 rm(filename, text)
 gc()  
}
```

Comment: How big are the data frames you are storing? Maybe every 1000 iterations you could write them to a file and then clear them. Are any other objects in your workspace? Models, perhaps? You could do something like `sort(sapply(ls(), object.size), decreasing = T)` to see how big your used objects are.

Comment: The size of dataframe is very small compared to my text files. It is 100MB total size. I am actually not appending the observations in dataframe. Rather, I am appending it directly in CSV in each iteration. I will definitely check the size of each object based on your mentioned method. I will let you know if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check which objects are taking memory and that you do not use anymore:

```
print(sapply(ls(), function(x) pryr::object_size(get(x))/1024/1024))
```

(EDIT: just saw the comment with this almost identical advice)

this line will give you the size in Megabytes of every object present in the environment (in RAM).

Alternatively if nothing appears, you can call `gc()` several times instead of once like:

```
rm(filename, text)
for (i in 1:3) gc()
```

It is usually more effective...
If nothing works, that could mean the memory is fragmented and thus RAM is free but unavailable to use as misplaced between data you still use.
The solution could be to run your scripts by chunks of files say 1000 by 1000.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will try this method and will let you know.

Comment: I use the code to check memory size of all the variables. Surprisingly, when I sum the size of all the variables using `sapply(ls(), function(x) pryr::object_size(get(x))/1024/1024)`, I got total used memory is 30.10MB after 200 iterations, but it shows me around 6GB memory for "Rstudio R session" as ~6GB in windows "Task Manager". Is there anything wrong?